# Call shuffle method once and use output multiple times in ruby

Tags: ruby, logic, shuffle

I have two classes in two seperate files. The script starts by executing file domain.rb

In the first file (domain.rb) I have the following code:

```
require 'message.rb'  

class Domain
def create_domain
  10.times do 
    puts "#{Message.site}"
   end
end
```

In the second file (message.rb) I have this peace of code:

```
class Message
   def self.site
     @site = [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].shuffle[0,7].join
     @site.concat("@example.com")
   end

   def other_method
     puts "#{Message.site} later in the text #{Message.site}"
   end
end
```

My Problem:

This way I'm executing the method .site three times ergo I'll receive 3 different outputs of shuffle method.

```
v9srm6z@example.com
b9rlgti@example.com
c96nve1@example.com
```

My Question: How can I ensure I can use v9srm6z@example.com three times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memoize the instance variable:

```
class Message
   def self.site
     @site ||= [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].
                 shuffle[0,7].
                 join.
                 concat("@example.com")
   end
   puts "#{Message.site} later in the text #{Message.site}"
end
```

*Sidenote:* Use [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-sample) with an argument instead of shuffling:

```
class Message
   def self.site
     @site ||= [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].
                 sample(8).
                 join.
                 concat("@example.com")
   end
end
```